# i needed a way to check data, is that exist or not on realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, qr-code

i having an qr code layout that been used for opening higher authority activity layout, and how can i make/search the code online on the firebase database that look like below here

[this what my firebase data look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYUbp.png)

below this what the code that can open to new activity, but i want the code was different each admin, so if the admin retire i dont need to change the code inside the app everytime

```
public class BarcodeScanner extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CodeScanner mCodeScanner;
    private static final String Code = "newsenyum";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_scanner);
        CodeScannerView scannerView = findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
        mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(this, scannerView);
        mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback () {
            @Override
            public void onDecoded(@NonNull final Result result) {
               BarcodeScanner.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        String codeFromScanner = result.getText(); // initialize the code from scanner

                        if(Code.equals (codeFromScanner.trim ())){
                            redirectToNewActivity ();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText (BarcodeScanner.this, "QRCode Tidak Dapat di Gunakan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ( );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        scannerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCodeScanner.startPreview();
            }
        });
    }



    private void redirectToNewActivity() {
        startActivity (new Intent (getApplicationContext ( ), AdminUID.class));
        finish ( );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCodeScanner.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mCodeScanner.releaseResources();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIExs.png)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo so i want the `private static final String Code = "newsenyum";` being on firebase admin account

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what you are looking for,

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to check a string that is exist on the realtime firebase that look like `barcode code : pa29h9h75dg`, something like checking if this string of text exist on the firebase but not only in one account

Comment: @AlexMamo maybe i tried to explain more specific on the top question, i alrd edit it, sorry if i got bad english here, hard to explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

To check if a particular bar code exists in the database, you need to use a Query object. So please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference adminRef = db.child("Admin");
Query queryByCode = adminRef.orderByChild("barcode code").equalTo("pa29h9h75dg");
queryByCode.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Barcode already exists.");

                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", id);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Barcode doesn't exist.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Lela
```

Comment: okok letme try it now

Comment: Yep. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: idk why but i cant get text from the qrcode on it

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the text? Are you referring to the `id`? If yes, check my updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried my solution from my edited answer, does it work?

Comment: not yet but letme try it now, and put the checkmark after it :)

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing your feedback.

Comment: its didnt show anything in my log, letme try to send full code that i've change https://pastebin.com/Jjre9wMg

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Does this line `Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());` print something? Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: nope i don't get any on my logcat

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: Yes it is, i will provide screenshoot on below the question

Comment: I cannot see the output. How do you check if the onComplete is triggered?

Comment: eh i dont know how, im sorry bout that

Comment: Add a log statement inside onComplete and check if it prints out something. If it isn't, then most likely you don't have an internet connection on user's device, right?

Comment: uhm i dont get anythin on logcat

Comment: Then make sure you have an internet connection. That explains why you aren't getting anything printed out.

Comment: well i can use the login part, and it need internet connection to firebase, but i dont know why its show nothing on the qr part

Comment: Try to use a minimum integration `db.child("test").setValue(true);` Is it something added to Firebase?